# Why does Typescript ignore my tsconfig.json inside Visual Studio Code?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I got my project setup like this

```
project/
|
+---src/
|   |
|   +---app/
|       |
|       sample.ts
|
+---typings/
+---tsconfig.json
```

and here's my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "rootDir": "src",
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "outDir": "dist"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "src/assets",
        "src/lib"
    ]
}
```

What I'm wondering is, why does VSC indicate errors such as

[image: Error Highlighting in VSC]

when clearly there is no error at all (`"experimentalDecorators": true` is set in `tsconfig.json`), and the app transpiles just fine? And it's not just decorators, `Promise` and the like is highlighted as well (I made sure to have `tsconfig.json` in the same folder as `typings` and I got the typings for `es6-shim` installed).

Not sure if it matters, but I'm on `typescript@2.0.0-dev.20160707` at the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Locate the folder `typescript` was installed to by `npm`, in my case this was:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\\lib
```

Among other files, there should be:

```
lib.d.ts
tsserver.js
```

inside. Now open settings:

```
File -> Preferences -> User Settings/Workspace Settings
```

This should open a file `settings.json`, add:

```
{
    "typescript.tsdk": "C:\\Users\\<username>\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\typescript\\lib"
}
```

(mind the double backslashes `\\`), save and - important - restart Visual Studio Code. Enjoy.

Comment: What happens if you remove `node_modules/` and reinstall it?

Comment: You should never reference your personal username in your code. This is very hard to maintain especially if you move your code to a new computer or need to share it with someone else. The above answer is better, IMO.

Comment: @TrentBing just do not commit `.vscode` folder to git!

Comment: @PavelMayorov I ALWAYS check the `.vscode` folder into Git. Why would you want to deal with different developers on the repo having different VS Code settings (formatter settings, ESLint settings, TypeScript versions, etc.) which conflict with the desired settings for the repo? The `.vscode` folder makes sure that all devs using VS Code are not stepping on each others' toes.

Answer (score 74):

## Short Answer

VS Code ignores your `tsconfig.json` when you use a newer version of TypeScript than the one that VS Code provides out of the box.

You are using TypeScript `2.0.0-dev.20160707`, so that is probably what is happening.

## How to use a newer TypeScript version in VS Code

**First**, install TypeScript into your `node_modules`. Choose stable or nightly.

```
npm install typescript --save-dev // stable
npm install typescript@next --save-dev // nightly
```

**Second**, add the resultant `lib` relative path to your `settings.json`. That is, open `settings.json` in VS Code via File > Settings > User Settings, and add the following property.

```
{
  "typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib"
}
```

**Note**, if you installed TypeScript globally (`-g`) instead of into your project's `node_modules`, then adjust your `typescript.tsdk` location appropriately.

**Third**, make sure you have a valid `tsconfig.json`. Here is an example.

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "filesGlob": [
        "src/**/*.ts",
        "test/**/*.ts",
        "typings/index.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

## [Documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/typescript#_using-newer-typescript-versions)

> VS Code ships with a recent stable version of TypeScript in the box. **If you want to use a newer version of TypeScript,** you can define the typescript.tsdk setting (File > Preferences > User/Workspace Settings) pointing to a directory containing the TypeScript tsserver.js and the corresponding lib.*.d.ts files. The directory path can be absolute or relative to the workspace directory. By using a relative path, you can easily share this workspace setting with your team and use the latest TypeScript version (npm install typescript@next). Refer to this blog post for more details on how to install the nightly builds of TypeScript. (emphasis added).

See also: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/01/28/announcing-typescript-1-8-beta/

Comment: For me, the crucial bit was a _valid_ `tsconfig.json` - it would be much more helpful if VSCode told you there was a problem with your `tsconfig.json`, rather than just silently ignoring it!!!

Comment: For me it was because I defined `include: ["./src/index.ts"]` in tsconfig. I did it so TypeScript would only generate  type definitions for included files (tree shaking), but it seems like it will make VS Code ignore local tsconfig.ts for all other files.

Comment: Shouldn't the location to typescript (written as relative path) be configured in the workspace settings?

Answer (score 32):

In my case, the problem was that the `.ts` file I was editing was not included in the `tsconfig.json`.

I've added a new `scripts/build.ts` file and in `tsconfig.json` I had:

```json
{
  include: ["src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

had to add:

```json
{
  include: ["src/**/*.ts", "scripts/**/*.ts"]
}
```

Comment: This is what fixed my issue, thanks. I just needed to change `src/*.ts` to `src/**/*.ts` and all my issues are gone, thanks!

Comment: This solved my stubborn VS Code problem as well! Thanks a lot!!!!! I had to add:
`include: ["src/**/*.ts"]`

Answer (score 3):

There is a trick that you may or may not have noticed. When you change **tsconfig**, it is not recognized by VS Code, and you have to restart TypeScript Server.

I was facing a similar case when I was working on merging 7 React apps into **Turborepo** monorepos, and was troubled by the fact that `tsconfig/.eslintrc` could not reflect in real-time when I made changes to them, so I built this small extension to monitor those config files and **Restart TypeScript / ESLint servers Automatically**. Hope it helps.

**VS Code extension:**

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=neotan.vscode-auto-restart-typescript-eslint-servers

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was that my tsconfig.json was in the wrong place. It was in the `.vscode` folder, but it should have been up a level.

I noticed this when I clicked on my Typescript version in the bottom right corner and the VSCode menu told me that no tsconfig file was found and prompted me to create one.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you **do not have** a `jsconfig.json` file or any other overwriting config file in your project. That solved the problem for me!

Answer (score 1):

i faced the same error, for me the problem was with the `"include": [...]` option, which was set incorrectly .(wasn't covering all the files in `src` folder)

Answer (score -1):

Try to install latest stable version of VS code

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35477631)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).