# VSCode is unable to detect the tsconfig that resides in the Next.js app created using NX

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, next.js, nrwl-nx

I created a new NX workspace by running:

```
npx create-nx-workspace@latest --preset=next --packageManager=yarn --skipGit
```

I have also created a shared lib by running:

```
npx nx g @nrwl/next:library components --directory=shared/ui/theme-v1.0 --component=false --tags=--tags=scope:themev1-ui,type:shared,platform:web --style=none --importPath=@my-app/shared/ui/theme-v1.0/components
```

Sharing the tsconfig.json available under the Next.js app:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "types": ["jest", "node"]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.js",
    "src/**/*.jsx",
    "next-env.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "jest.config.ts"]
}
```

I ran `npx nx lint` and found no errors.

But, in my VSCode, the tsconfig is not getting detected due to which I can see false errors. Sharing the screenshot of the issue and folder structure:

[image: VSCode No TSConfig in Footer]

As you can see in the screenshot, there are errors and on hovering over the selected language mode, we can see the `No tsconfig.json` message.

But, this issue doesn't exist for any of the libs. Sharing the screenshot of the same:

[image]

I can see that this only happens with the Next.js project.

I tried creating a tsconfig.app.json file and extending tsconfig.json but to no avail. Tried reloading VSCode too. I am not quite sure if it's related to VSCode or NX set-up. I am using the workspace typescript and not the one provided by VSCode.

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nx serve",
    "build": "nx build",
    "test": "nx test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@nrwl/next": "15.3.3",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "next": "13.0.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "0.13.7",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@nrwl/cypress": "15.3.3",
    "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "15.3.3",
    "@nrwl/jest": "15.3.3",
    "@nrwl/linter": "15.3.3",
    "@nrwl/nx-cloud": "latest",
    "@nrwl/react": "15.3.3",
    "@nrwl/web": "15.3.3",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "15.3.3",
    "@swc/core": "^1.2.173",
    "@swc/jest": "0.2.20",
    "@testing-library/react": "13.4.0",
    "@types/jest": "28.1.1",
    "@types/node": "18.11.9",
    "@types/react": "18.0.25",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.9",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.36.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.36.1",
    "babel-jest": "28.1.1",
    "cypress": "^11.0.0",
    "eslint": "~8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.10.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.31.11",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.6.0",
    "jest": "28.1.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "28.1.1",
    "nx": "15.3.3",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "ts-jest": "28.0.5",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "typescript": "~4.8.2"
  }
}
```

NX.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/nx/schemas/nx-schema.json",
  "npmScope": "my-app",
  "tasksRunnerOptions": {
    "default": {
      "runner": "@nrwl/nx-cloud",
      "options": {
        "cacheableOperations": [
          "build",
          "lint",
          "test",
          "e2e"
        ],
        "accessToken": "some access token"
      }
    }
  },
  "targetDefaults": {
    "build": {
      "dependsOn": [
        "^build"
      ],
      "inputs": [
        "production",
        "^production"
      ]
    },
    "test": {
      "inputs": [
        "default",
        "^production",
        "{workspaceRoot}/jest.preset.js"
      ]
    },
    "e2e": {
      "inputs": [
        "default",
        "^production"
      ]
    },
    "lint": {
      "inputs": [
        "default",
        "{workspaceRoot}/.eslintrc.json"
      ]
    }
  },
  "namedInputs": {
    "default": [
      "{projectRoot}/**/*",
      "sharedGlobals"
    ],
    "production": [
      "default",
      "!{projectRoot}/**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x)?(.snap)",
      "!{projectRoot}/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "!{projectRoot}/jest.config.[jt]s",
      "!{projectRoot}/.eslintrc.json"
    ],
    "sharedGlobals": [
      "{workspaceRoot}/babel.config.json"
    ]
  },
  "generators": {
    "@nrwl/react": {
      "application": {
        "babel": true
      }
    },
    "@nrwl/next": {
      "application": {
        "style": "css",
        "linter": "eslint"
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "my-app"
}
```

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/38862621/3008809

Comment: @Arkadi I am already using the workspace typescript and not the one provided by VSCode.

Answer (score 3):

I found the issue. The issue seems to be with the `include` property set by the @nrwl/next team.

When we create a new app, the `include` property is set to:

```
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.js",
    "src/**/*.jsx",
    "next-env.d.ts"
  ]
```

But, the Next.js app doesn't have a `src/` directory. So, it needs to be set to:

```
"include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "**/*.js", "**/*.jsx", "next-env.d.ts"]
```

I have raised a GitHub ticket as well - https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/13861